# App crashes between quick navigation between tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I am building application that uses tab bar.

I have say A & B tab.

- When I click on tab A, then it takes time for loading data from server.
- Similarly, when I click on tab B, it takes time loading.
- If click on tab A and wait until it loads all data, and then move to tab B, it works fine.
- If I click on tab A and move to tab B while A was still loading data from server, it crashes the app.

I tried to unload the view at view did unload method. But, it did not work.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Comment: post your code for reference.

Comment: there are multiple views,,and so it is not possible to post exact problem. But,I am sure that problem is being caused by one view calling data from web service is still processing when i move to next tab view

Comment: call your WS in asynchronous type.

Comment: I suggest setting an exception breakpoint, and then look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

in each view loaded by tab bar controller, I added self.view = nil; for each view will disappear method. This solved by problem. May be this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to answer. There could be many possible causes. However, my first guess would be that you're dispatching your NSURLConnection completion handler to the main queue and trying to update the UI, which is no longer in sync.

In other words, you start on tab A and the download commences asynchronously. You then switch to tab B in your UI, starting the second download on another queue. Your tab A download completes, and the completion handler is then dispatched to the main queue. In that completion handler, you may have code to, for example, reload a UITableView on tab A. But since you are no longer on tab A, that view controller (and all of its associated views) do not currently exist in your program's life cycle. If you're not properly checking for nil responses, etc., this could create a crash.

Another less likely possibility is you are running out of memory. Easy to test for this: simply monitor the memory usage as you navigate through the app. Your app may crash if it doesn't properly respond to a memory warning. This would be possible if you were using an NSURLCache, perhaps, and committing too much memory to both download requests simultaneously.